# Javascript - convert HTML div with SVG to image

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, html2canvas

I use Highcharts to draw a graph.

I want to add "export to PNG" option that includes both Highcharts graph and outer div. When using Highcharts export, I'm unable to add the outer div containing the chart.

I saw several examples here using html2canvas. When I tried using it, the Highcharts' SVG element wansn't included in the output image.

Does anyone know a solution, better than trying to merge SVG image inside outer HTML div image?

Update -

Using the latest version of html2canvas fixed that issue, however the output is slightly different:

Original:
[image]

html2canvas output:

[image]

As you can see some elements are rendered twice in different locations.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Would this work? http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/

Comment: I wrote [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eqjmu644/) for an other question about svg to bitmap (still waiting for it to reopen), maybe you could use it before calling html2canvas, it think it covers more edge cases than html2canvas svgToPng method

Comment: @crclayton The result is the same - no SVG objects.

Comment: @Kaiido In your example there is not div outside SVG element.

Comment: No, here is the link for the question that made me write this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506122/export-svg-as-bitmap I suspect there is something like this or an other edge case that makes your svg impossible to transform as bitmap. But it doesn't cover the html to bitmap at all. If it doesn't work and even if it does, I'd be highly interested in seeing the outputed svg code you have.

Comment: I've used the updated html2canvas version (alpha1) and now it almost works, but still the image is not exact as the html.

Comment: @BobTheBuilder proof of concept : https://jsfiddle.net/eqjmu644/1/

Comment: Thanx @Kaiido. I think the issue now is some css styles that are not supported yet.

Comment: that's why we need your markup. But I have to admit that I forgot about external CSS, so thank you, I'll be able to improve it more.

Comment: For converting svg to images I can recommend `canvg`.

Comment: @hgoebl canvg fails with some special features like filters jsfiddle.net/L3hondLn/248, it even taints the canvas while not needed...
And it crashes with "in document" stylesheets https://jsfiddle.net/L3hondLn/250/

Comment: @hgoebl canvg can only convert svg element. It cannot convert div containing svg.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are dealing with a few edge cases of svg to bitmap conversion.

I am not sure which method html2canvas uses, but it certainly lacks in something here.

I wrote a function that handles some of theses edge cases that you could use before calling html2canvas, since it is able to draw bitmaps without any problem.

```js
// without converting the svg to png
html2canvas(contentDiv, {
    onrendered: function(can) {
      dirty.appendChild(can);
    }
  });
  
// first convert your svg to png
exportInlineSVG(svg, function(data, canvas) {
  svg.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, svg);
  // then call html2canvas
  html2canvas(contentDiv, {
    onrendered: function(can) {
      can.id = 'canvas';
      clean.appendChild(can);
    }
  });
})


function exportInlineSVG(svg, receiver, params, quality) {
  if (!svg || !svg.nodeName || svg.nodeName !== 'svg') {
    console.error('Wrong arguments : should be \n exportSVG(SVGElement, function([dataURL],[canvasElement]) || IMGElement || CanvasElement [, String_toDataURL_Params, Float_Params_quality])')
    return;
  }

  var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
  var clone;
  // This will convert an external image to a dataURL
  var toDataURL = function(image) {

    var img = new Image();
    // CORS workaround, this won't work in IE<11
    // If you are sure you don't need it, remove the next line and the double onerror handler
    // First try with crossorigin set, it should fire an error if not needed
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

    img.onload = function() {
      // we should now be able to draw it without tainting the canvas
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var bbox = image.getBBox();
      canvas.width = bbox.width;
      canvas.height = bbox.height;
      // draw the loaded image
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, bbox.width, bbox.height);
      // set our original <image>'s href attribute to the dataURL of our canvas
      image.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href', canvas.toDataURL());
      // that was the last one
      if (++encoded === total) exportDoc()
    }

    // No CORS set in the response  
    img.onerror = function() {
        // save the src
        var oldSrc = this.src;
        // there is an other problem
        this.onerror = function() {
            console.warn('failed to load an image at : ', this.src);
            if (--total === encoded && encoded > 0) exportDoc();
          }
          // remove the crossorigin attribute
        this.removeAttribute('crossorigin');
        // retry
        this.src = '';
        this.src = oldSrc;
      }
      // load our external image into our img
    img.src = image.getAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href');
  }

  // The final function that will export our svgNode to our receiver
  var exportDoc = function() {
      // check if our svgNode has width and height properties set to absolute values
      // otherwise, canvas won't be able to draw it
      var bbox = svg.getBBox();
      // avoid modifying the original one
      clone = svg.cloneNode(true);
      if (svg.width.baseVal.unitType !== 1) clone.setAttribute('width', bbox.width);
      if (svg.height.baseVal.unitType !== 1) clone.setAttribute('height', bbox.height);

      parseStyles();

      // serialize our node
      var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(clone);
      // remember to encode special chars
      var svgURL = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);

      var svgImg = new Image();

      svgImg.onload = function() {
        // if we set a canvas as receiver, then use it
        // otherwise create a new one
        var canvas = (receiver && receiver.nodeName === 'CANVAS') ? receiver : document.createElement('canvas');
        // IE11 doesn't set a width on svg images...
        canvas.width = this.width || bbox.width;
        canvas.height = this.height || bbox.height;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // try to catch IE
        try {
          // if we set an <img> as receiver
          if (receiver.nodeName === 'IMG') {
            // make the img looks like the svg
            receiver.setAttribute('style', getSVGStyles(receiver));
            receiver.src = canvas.toDataURL(params, quality);
          } else {
            // make the canvas looks like the canvas
            canvas.setAttribute('style', getSVGStyles(canvas));
            // a container element
            if (receiver.appendChild && receiver !== canvas)
              receiver.appendChild(canvas);
            // if we set a function
            else if (typeof receiver === 'function')
              receiver(canvas.toDataURL(params, quality), canvas);
          }
        } catch (ie) {
          console.warn("Your ~browser~ has tainted the canvas.\n The canvas is returned");
          if (receiver.nodeName === 'IMG') receiver.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, receiver);
          else receiver(null, canvas);
        }
      }
      svgImg.onerror = function(e) {
        if (svg._cleanedNS) {
          console.error("Couldn't export svg, please check that the svgElement passed is a valid svg document.");
          return;
        }
        // Some non-standard NameSpaces can cause this issues
        // This will remove them all
        function cleanNS(el) {
          var attr = el.attributes;
          for (var i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
            if (attr[i].name.indexOf(':') > -1) el.removeAttribute(attr[i].name)
          }
        }
        cleanNS(svg);
        for (var i = 0; i < svg.children.length; i++)
          cleanNS(svg.children[i]);
        svg._cleanedNS = true;
        // retry the export
        exportDoc();
      }
      svgImg.src = svgURL;
    }
    // ToDo : find a way to get only usefull rules
  var parseStyles = function() {
    var styleS = [],i;
    // transform the live StyleSheetList to an array to avoid endless loop
    for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
      styleS.push(document.styleSheets[i]);
    // Do we have a `<defs>` element already ?
    var defs = clone.querySelector('defs') || document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
    if (!defs.parentNode)
      clone.insertBefore(defs, clone.firstElementChild);

    // iterate through all document's stylesheets
    for (i = 0; i < styleS.length; i++) {
      var style = document.createElement('style');
      var rules = styleS[i].cssRules,
        l = rules.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < l; j++)
        style.innerHTML += rules[j].cssText + '\n';

      defs.appendChild(style);
    }
    // small hack to avoid border and margins being applied inside the <img>
    var s = clone.style;
    s.border = s.padding = s.margin = 0;
    s.transform = 'initial';
  }
  var getSVGStyles = function(node) {
    var dest = node.cloneNode(true);
    svg.parentNode.insertBefore(dest, svg);
    var dest_comp = getComputedStyle(dest);
    var svg_comp = getComputedStyle(svg);
    var mods = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < svg_comp.length; i++) {
      if (svg_comp[svg_comp[i]] !== dest_comp[svg_comp[i]])
        mods += svg_comp[i] + ':' + svg_comp[svg_comp[i]] + ';';
    }
    svg.parentNode.removeChild(dest);
    return mods;
  }

  var images = svg.querySelectorAll('image'),
    total = images.length,
    encoded = 0;
  // Loop through all our <images> elements
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    // check if the image is external
    if (images[i].getAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href').indexOf('data:image') < 0)
      toDataURL(images[i]);
    // else increment our counter
    else if (++encoded === total) exportDoc()
  }
  // if there were no <image> element
  if (total === 0) exportDoc();
}
```

```css
rect {
  fill: blue;
  transform: translate(35px) rotate(45deg);
}
div {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block
}
#svg {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#canvas { border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentDiv">
  <p>Some html content</p>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" width="200">
    <defs>
      <filter id="Alien" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feComponentTransfer>
          <fefuncR type="table" tablevalues="1 0 1" />
        </feComponentTransfer>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <image filter="url(#Alien)" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="clean">clean:<br></div>
<div id="dirty">dirty :<br></div>
```

**Note :**
From this question, I started to write a full exportInlineSVG function that you can find [here](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG-to-Bitmap/blob/master/SVG2Bitmap.js).

Comment: I just added the import style sheets method, and it should certainly be improved. e.g if there is a border set on the svg element in one of the stylesheets, this will be badly drawn in my function, but not in the html2canvas one... I didn't find any perfect solution for this yet but  I'll keep searching. Also one thing that could and maybe should be done, is to set the retuned canvas id and classes to the same the svg element were, so the non-svg-specific styles still apply on the canvas version.

Comment: when I was tried, it is showing as black image. Please can you point me where i went wrong?

Comment: @CJRamki, without seeing your code, no I can't tell you what's wrong. But, from this answer, I wrote [this script](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap) which might handle even more cases, and fix some bugs. If it still doesn't work, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap/issues/new) with some [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so I can see what is wrong.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for your response. I did a mistake. I was applied color and fill properties to parent element. After that I tried apply style to svg element. Now working like charm...

Comment: @Kaiido well working with chrome, in firefox it is throwing `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` at `var rules = styleS[i].cssRules,` Script stopped working in Firefox

Comment: @CJRamki Yep, that should be wrapped in a `try catch` block. Please use the updated script here : https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap/blob/master/SVG2Bitmap.js such bugs are already fixed and if you find other ones, please fill an issue.

Comment: @Kaiido getting `SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified.` error in safari at line `if ((svg.matches && svg.matches(selector)) || svg.querySelector(selector)) {`. line number `294` in source is.

Comment: @CJRamki, thanks for the feedback, just pushed a fix (I hope it works for you). next time please [fill an issue](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap/issues/new) on the project's github page, so is not the place for it.