# html2canvas ignores my svg elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, html2canvas

I try to **print** screen of my page and then save it into `base64`, it works good but it looks like that *svg* elements are ignored, and some *css* styles work bad, like `:before` and `:after`, original page looks - [image]

but after conversion it looks like this - [image]

You can see the *circle* on right side is ignore, and arrow in top menu and same `:before` and `:after` on tabs and add new tab button (+). My convert code looks -

```
printOnePage(){
        document.getElementById('helpPage').style.display= 'none';
        let page = document.getElementById('appContainer');
        html2canvas(page,{
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                console.log(document.getElementById('img_val'));
                //document.getElementById("phpSendForm").submit();
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('helpPage').style.display= '';

    }
```

Any tips what can cause this ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10722025/863110) answer. And here is the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3976034/863110)

Comment: Or just update your html2canvas version...

Comment: @Kaiido I updated, but still same.

Comment: He added some html2canvas.svg.js, but i don't know how to work with it

Comment: Then you'll need to show us your svg markup, [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33595847/3702797) may help

Answer (score 2):

Html2canvas ignores your svg elements if the CSS properties are in the CSS page.

I had the following problem: I had an svg block and inside a line block. And html2canvas capture the div block but doesn't capture my line. The style of each has been declared in the CSS page with the class name of these two elements.

And the solution was just to put the CSS properties inside the svg and line tag, like this:

```
<div>
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
<line style="cursor: pointer; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2;" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: what is a "CSS page"? can you please clarify by using broadly understood terminology, please?

Comment: Yeah sure sorry. So the CSS page is for me the file .css (page=file). In many projects you have a file .html, .js and a file .css, that you import for instance in your html file. And with html2canvas I observe that if my properties were declared in the file .css, they were not captured by html2canvas. So I declare the CSS as "inline CSS"

Answer (score -1):

html2canvas support **SVG rendering** since[0.5.0-alpha1](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/tag/0.5.0-alpha1) just

1. update
2. add the **allowTaint** property.

like blow:

```
html2canvas(copyDom[0], {
        useCORS: true,
        imageTimeout:0,
        allowTaint: true //you can add this property
    }).then(function (canvas) {})
```