# capture whole div with svg in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I want to capture whole div as image and save on local for proof.I have searched and read many articles about svg to image or div to image.

I have tried some js library for this.But when i try to capture image from div then some captures only div content and some captures only svg content.

[s.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSKsX.jpg) , [a.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIo0d.jpg)

```js
html2canvas(contentDiv, {
    onrendered: function(can) {
      dirty.appendChild(can);
    }
  });
// first convert your svg to png
exportInlineSVG(svg, function(data, canvas) {
  svg.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, svg);
  // then call html2canvas
  html2canvas(contentDiv, {
    onrendered: function(can) {
      can.id = 'canvas';
      clean.appendChild(can);
    }
  });
})


function exportInlineSVG(svg, receiver, params, quality) {
  if (!svg || !svg.nodeName || svg.nodeName !== 'svg') {
    console.error('Wrong arguments : should be \n exportSVG(SVGElement, function([dataURL],[canvasElement]) || IMGElement || CanvasElement [, String_toDataURL_Params, Float_Params_quality])')
    return;
  }

  var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
  var clone;
  // This will convert an external image to a dataURL
  var toDataURL = function(image) {

    var img = new Image();
    // CORS workaround, this won't work in IE<11
    // If you are sure you don't need it, remove the next line and the double onerror handler
    // First try with crossorigin set, it should fire an error if not needed
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

    img.onload = function() {
      // we should now be able to draw it without tainting the canvas
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var bbox = image.getBBox();
      canvas.width = bbox.width;
      canvas.height = bbox.height;
      // draw the loaded image
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, bbox.width, bbox.height);
      // set our original <image>'s href attribute to the dataURL of our canvas
      image.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href', canvas.toDataURL());
      // that was the last one
      if (++encoded === total) exportDoc()
    }

    // No CORS set in the response    
    img.onerror = function() {
        // save the src
        var oldSrc = this.src;
        // there is an other problem
        this.onerror = function() {
            console.warn('failed to load an image at : ', this.src);
            if (--total === encoded && encoded > 0) exportDoc();
          }
          // remove the crossorigin attribute
        this.removeAttribute('crossorigin');
        // retry
        this.src = '';
        this.src = oldSrc;
      }
      // load our external image into our img
    img.src = image.getAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href');
  }

  // The final function that will export our svgNode to our receiver
  var exportDoc = function() {
      // check if our svgNode has width and height properties set to absolute values
      // otherwise, canvas won't be able to draw it
      var bbox = svg.getBBox();
      // avoid modifying the original one
      clone = svg.cloneNode(true);
      if (svg.width.baseVal.unitType !== 1) clone.setAttribute('width', bbox.width);
      if (svg.height.baseVal.unitType !== 1) clone.setAttribute('height', bbox.height);

      parseStyles();

      // serialize our node
      var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(clone);
      // remember to encode special chars
      var svgURL = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);

      var svgImg = new Image();

      svgImg.onload = function() {
        // if we set a canvas as receiver, then use it
        // otherwise create a new one
        var canvas = (receiver && receiver.nodeName === 'CANVAS') ? receiver : document.createElement('canvas');
        // IE11 doesn't set a width on svg images...
        canvas.width = this.width || bbox.width;
        canvas.height = this.height || bbox.height;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // try to catch IE
        try {
          // if we set an <img> as receiver
          if (receiver.nodeName === 'IMG') {
            // make the img looks like the svg
            receiver.setAttribute('style', getSVGStyles(receiver));
            receiver.src = canvas.toDataURL(params, quality);
          } else {
            // make the canvas looks like the canvas
            canvas.setAttribute('style', getSVGStyles(canvas));
            // a container element
            if (receiver.appendChild && receiver !== canvas)
              receiver.appendChild(canvas);
            // if we set a function
            else if (typeof receiver === 'function')
              receiver(canvas.toDataURL(params, quality), canvas);
          }
        } catch (ie) {
          console.warn("Your ~browser~ has tainted the canvas.\n The canvas is returned");
          if (receiver.nodeName === 'IMG') receiver.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, receiver);
          else receiver(null, canvas);
        }
      }
      svgImg.onerror = function(e) {
        if (svg._cleanedNS) {
          console.error("Couldn't export svg, please check that the svgElement passed is a valid svg document.");
          return;
        }
        // Some non-standard NameSpaces can cause this issues
        // This will remove them all
        function cleanNS(el) {
          var attr = el.attributes;
          for (var i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
            if (attr[i].name.indexOf(':') > -1) el.removeAttribute(attr[i].name)
          }
        }
        cleanNS(svg);
        for (var i = 0; i < svg.children.length; i++)
          cleanNS(svg.children[i]);
        svg._cleanedNS = true;
        // retry the export
        exportDoc();
      }
      svgImg.src = svgURL;
    }
    // ToDo : find a way to get only usefull rules
  var parseStyles = function() {
    var styleS = [],i;
    // transform the live StyleSheetList to an array to avoid endless loop
    for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
      styleS.push(document.styleSheets[i]);
    // Do we have a `<defs>` element already ?
    var defs = clone.querySelector('defs') || document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
    if (!defs.parentNode)
      clone.insertBefore(defs, clone.firstElementChild);

    // iterate through all document's stylesheets
    for (i = 0; i < styleS.length; i++) {
      var style = document.createElement('style');
      var rules = styleS[i].cssRules,
        l = rules.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < l; j++)
        style.innerHTML += rules[j].cssText + '\n';

      defs.appendChild(style);
    }
    // small hack to avoid border and margins being applied inside the <img>
    var s = clone.style;
    s.border = s.padding = s.margin = 0;
    s.transform = 'initial';
  }
  var getSVGStyles = function(node) {
    var dest = node.cloneNode(true);
    svg.parentNode.insertBefore(dest, svg);
    var dest_comp = getComputedStyle(dest);
    var svg_comp = getComputedStyle(svg);
    var mods = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < svg_comp.length; i++) {
      if (svg_comp[svg_comp[i]] !== dest_comp[svg_comp[i]])
        mods += svg_comp[i] + ':' + svg_comp[svg_comp[i]] + ';';
    }
    svg.parentNode.removeChild(dest);
    return mods;
  }

  var images = svg.querySelectorAll('image'),
    total = images.length,
    encoded = 0;
  // Loop through all our <images> elements
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    // check if the image is external
    if (images[i].getAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href').indexOf('data:image') < 0)
      toDataURL(images[i]);
    // else increment our counter
    else if (++encoded === total) exportDoc()
  }
  // if there were no <image> element
  if (total === 0) exportDoc();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentDiv" style="width: 50%;">
  <img class="" src="s.jpg" width="75%">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" height="100%">
    <defs>  
      <clipPath id="my-path">
        <text id="texty" style="font-weight:bold;" x="60" y="300" font-size="60">test</text>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <image xlink:href="a.jpg" clip-path="url(#my-path)" width="100%" height="100%" id="filler" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="clean">clean:<br></div>
<div id="dirty">dirty :<br></div>
<style type="text/css">
 svg {
  position: relative; 
  top: -531px;
  left: 120px;
 }
</style>
```

I have attached three images. s.jpg image is my main image which is inside in main div. It is main image where user can write their name with texture color. To write text i have used svg inside main div and for texture i have used a.jpg as hidden image.

I used html2canvas js library to convert div into image but i did not get my desired output. Please help me to find out solution for this problem. Thanx in advance

Comment: how exactly do you want the output to look like?

Comment: http://testing.devserver.co.in/demo/download.png -- see link the output which i want

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`exportInlineSVG`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595847/javascript-convert-html-div-with-svg-to-image/33599357) function you're using. There has been a few updates on this function in this [now dead project](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap/blob/master/SVG2Bitmap.js) since I posted this answer. But I can't get what's your problem. Don't you have an error message in the console ? Also, the first `html2canvas` call was well commented `// without converting the svg to png` and was meant to show the usefulness of doing it.

Comment: I want to write text with a hidden image on a different image in svg. for e.g : s.jpg is my main image where i want to write text and a.jpg is my hidden image in svg which i used for text color. And I have shared also a link in comment which is the output i want. you first run my code without javascript and see output of created image which i want to be capture as a proof. Now run my code with javascript image will be created but text not appeard in image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, very easy to use and works everytime :

[Dom-To-Image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image)

Answer (score 0):

you can use saveSvgAsPng.js where you have to pass the svg element id along with file name to the image

in my case

```
saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById('canvassvg'), "structure.png");
```

which stores the image in your temp or browser downloads location
(OR)
if you want to store it on server

convert the innerhtml content of of your main tag , i.e., from svg to /svg  to base64 and use the base64 to image converter in the backend

```
var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( svgobj );

var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );

var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

var img = document.createElement( "img" );

    function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
})));


svgData= btoa(encodeURIComponent(svgData).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
    function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
}));
img.setAttribute( "src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + svgData );
var canvasd='';
img.onload = function() {
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );


    canvasd = canvas.toDataURL( "image/svg+xml" );

  -base64 data is in canvasd
  -ajax call to store to backend



};


return;
```